# Fatal error: Call to Undefined Function Post

Tags: php, forms, http, post

I am just getting used to PHP and have a website where people can unsubscribe from a mailing list, this email address needs to be sent to a database. I will use a general www for the posting http://.

Here is the error I am receiving:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_post_fields() in
>   /home/mspace/public_html/mysite.com/application/views/forms/unsubscribe.php
>   on line 7

Here is line 7:

```
$response = http_post_fields("http://mywebsite.com/DDM/Import.cfc?method=submitRecord&ClientID=1&DataSourceID=1234&Token=1234&TokenPassword=1234", $fields);
```

I think it is referring to the http_post_fields, but not sure how to post this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to get all the key value pairs? Do you want `$response` to be an array of key value pairs? e.g. method = submit; token = 1234...etc

Answer (score 5):

you need to install [pecl_http](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) extension and enable it, for [http_post_fields()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-fields.php) to work
. Or an alternative solution would be to use a custom function like:

```
function http_post_flds($url, $data, $headers=null) {   
    $data = http_build_query($data);    
    $opts = array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'content' => $data));

    if($headers) {
        $opts['http']['header'] = $headers;
    }
    $st = stream_context_create($opts);
    $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $st);

    if(!$fp) {
        return false;
    }
    return stream_get_contents($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the [`pecl_http`](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) package. Or if you cannot install this package in your server you can use [`cURL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) as well:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://mywebsite.com/DDM/Import.cfc?method=submitRecord&ClientID=1&DataSourceID=1234&Token=1234&TokenPassword=1234");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Of course, this makes sense now! thanks. Regarding performance: curl should perform better, because this is compiled code. However pecl_http is simpler to use (my opinion)